# How to check the length of a MSMQ

Tags: c#, asp.net, configuration, message-queue, msmq

I have a private queue on a server A and I want to check the length or no of messages in the queue using C#.
I have tried searching online, but nothing concrete.
I have code deployed on Server B but they are on same network.
Is there anyway to check from Server B to Server A using C#?

Comment: What type of message queue? MSMQ?

Comment: sorry updated...it is MSMQ

Comment: I'd suggest looking at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3869022/is-there-a-way-to-check-how-many-messages-are-in-a-msmq-queue?rq=1. None of the options are particularly elegant though.