# Getting MSMQ counts via python

Tags: python, msmq

I've got a linux webserver running Flask and I want to write a frontend to display MSMQ counts from a remote windows server.  I've tried using win32com.client (on windows) using the Peek() method but it is too slow for large queue counts.  What options do i have for fetching queue counts?

Comment: Could you please show how to get queue count with `Peek()` method? As far as I understand 'Peek()' method always fetches the top message from the queue.

Answer (score 0):

Are you bound to Python only solution?

Perhaps you can write a service based on .NET which exposes an HTTP API and queries MSMQ using some internals stuff demonstrated in [Is there a way to check how many messages are in a MSMQ Queue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3869022/is-there-a-way-to-check-how-many-messages-are-in-a-msmq-queue)

Comment: I'm not, but i don't know .NET.

Comment: @user3727436 perhaps you could update your question and share with us what languages (other than Python) are you familiar with?