# How to identify if a private message queue (MSMQ) has exceeded its message storage limit using C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, msmq

Is there a way using C# to identify whether a private MSMQ has exceeded it's storage limit (KB)?

In the following example I created a private MSMQ using the Computer Management console and I set the storage limit to 100 KB.

[image]

I send messages to the queue using a simple c# program which works fine. I would like to be able to figure out when the limit has been reached in order to stop sending messages.

```
MessageQueue msgQ =new MessageQueue(".\\Private$\\name_of_queue");
msgQ.Send(msg);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Maximum Size of Queue

Use the [MessageQueue.MaximumQueueSize Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.messaging.messagequeue.maximumqueuesize) to get the queue's maximum size.

> The maximum size, in kilobytes, of the queue. The Message Queuing
> default specifies that no limit exists.

So, something like this should work:

```cs
var msgQ = new MessageQueue(".\\Private$\\name_of_queue");
long size = msgQ.MaximumQueueSize;
```

### Size of Queue

Use the [PerformanceCounter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.performancecounter) to get the current size of the queue:

```cs
var bytesCounter = new PerformanceCounter( 
    "MSMQ Queue", 
    "Bytes in Queue", 
    Environment.MachineName + "\\private$\\queue-name");
```

Looks like there are two different queries to get the size of the current queue:

| Query | Description |
| --- | --- |
| Bytes in Queue | Shows the total number of bytes that currently reside **in the queue**. For the computer queue instance, this represents **the dead letter queue**. |
| Bytes in Journal Queue | Shows the total number of bytes that reside **in the journal queue**. For the computer queue instance, this represents **the computer journal queue**. |

The above queries were found on MSDN in a now deprecated section of [MSMQ Queue Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2003/cc728409(v=ws.10)). However, I believe the queries are still valid.

Comment: MaximumQueueSize will return the maximum size of the queue e.g. 100 KB on my example above not the current size of the queue.

Comment: @StamatisTiniakos - yep, misread the question. Not entirely sure, but you will likely need a query with the `PerformanceCounter` or similar, ex: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13139144/9664

Comment: I used the PerformanceCounter as suggested and it works. Happy to accept your answer if you update it with the following: var bytesCounter = new PerformanceCounter(
                    "MSMQ Queue",
                    "Bytes in Queue",
                    Environment.MachineName + "\\private$\\queue-name");

Comment: @StamatisTiniakos - good information. I added a bit more context/information to the answer as well.